# Свои скрипты для элементов Yii2

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Добрый день, такой вопрос, мне в кнопку

```
Html::a('Удалить', ['app/delete', 'idDelete' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']);
```

Нужно добавить JS скрипт проверки `confirm` , однако если в массив `options` передаю значение `'onclick'=>confirm('Удалить?')` он вообще в коде элемента не появляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
<?php echo Html::a('Удалить', ['app/delete', 'idDelete' => $model->id], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Вы точно хотите удалить?',
        'method' => 'post',
    ],
]) ?>
```

если не получится, то попробуйте так:

```
...
[ 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
  'data-confirm' => 'Вы точно хотите удалить?', 
  'data-method' => 'post',
]
...
```

Comment: К сожалению опять таки нет, в коде элемента только значение class'a

Comment: @KOTJlETA а что ожидается увидеть? он ж там где-то в скрипте зашит. нажимать пробовал?

Comment: @KOTJlETA а так `[
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger','data-confirm' => 'Do you realy want to delete the item?',
                        'data-method' => 'post',]` ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @KOTJlETA а что именно? то, что в ответе или то, что в комментарии?

Comment: Помогло то что написано в коментари

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо)